# display a map result (angular 2)

Tags: angular

I have some problems to display an object in angular2

This is my Object which is an array of object and onother value)

[image]

That's how I retrieve it :

[image]

and that's how I try to display it in html

[image]
[image]

- The first question is how to display it?
- The second question how to modify the "res.errorMessage[0]" to res
  only? (because I could have many objects in the res ...)

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `res.errorMessage[0]`, errorMessage is not an array (there is not even a `errorMessage` in your response). just `.map(res => res.json())` and access the error message like you have `{{result.errorMsg}}`

Comment: Okay, now I saw that this object is apparently part of an array of the response? So how does your complete JSON look like? :) And PS, always add your code as code in your question, not pictures ;)

Comment: that's right. it's a part of an array of the response (subscribe is done in the service.component). My object looks like that (see updated picture)

PS : Ok good to know ;)

Comment: now you could see the object like i receive it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined. Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556213/typeerror-cannot-read-property-something-of-undefined-angular-2)

Comment: @n00dl3 I would agree this is a dupe (was thinking of marking it myself), but this wouldn't really answer both of the OP's questions...?

Comment: Glad to hear that someone did understand the second question :-D !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have several object, you'd want to extract the array from the response, like so:

```
.map(res => res.json().errorMessage)
```

Then you can iterate your `result` array and display the `errorMsg`:

```
<div *ngFor="let r of result"> {{r.errorMsg}}</div>
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aUydN3KB0TJ3rWNUsoxz?p=preview)

As to your first question, this is asynchronous, and you are pulling one object off the response. Since data retrieval is asynchronous, you are getting an `undefined` error, as your `result`-object is undefined at the point you are trying to display it in the template. This can be solved by using e.g the safe navigation operator:

```
{{result?.errorMsg}}
```

Here's more info: [Cannot read property "totalPrice" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558821/cannot-read-property-totalprice-of-undefined)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you get an observable from the async request as you are subscribing to it:

```js
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(result => this.result = result.errorMessage[0]);
```

Now `{{result.errorMsg}}` would print the message it holds.